# Update many entities in one WCF call versus hitting the WCF service for each entity to update

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I work on a multi-tier application and I need to optimize a long-running process in three ways :

1. Avoiding EF update concurrency problems.
2. Improving speed.
3. Informing the user of the progress.

Actually, the client code calls a WCF service using a method **that does all the work** (*evaluating the number of entities to update*, *querying the entities to update*, *updating them* and finally, *saving them back to the database*).

The process is very long and **nothing is sent back to the user except the final result** once the process is done. The user can stay in front of the wait form for up to 10 minutes, not knowing what is happening.

The number, and depth of the queried entities can become really big and I sometimes hit OutOfMemoryExceptions. I had to change the service method to process entity updates 100 entities at a time, so my DbContext will be refreshed often and won't become too big.

My actual problem is that I cannot inform the user each time an entity is updated because **my service method does the whole process before returning it's result to the user.**

I read about implementing a duplex service but since I have to return **two different callbacks** to the user (one callback to *return the number of entities to update* and another callback *for the result of each entity update*) I have to use multiple interface inheritance on a generic callback interface and it's becoming a little messy (well, to my taste).

Wouldn't it be better to have one WCF service method to return the number of entities to evaluate, and another WCF method that will return a simple entity update result, which will be hit for every entity to update ? My DBContext will be living only for the time of a single entity update, so it would not grow very much, which I think is good. **However, I am concerned about hitting the WCF service really often during that process**.

What are you thoughts ? What can you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about adding a WCF host to your client? That way you get full two way comms.

Client connects to server and gives server connection details back to client
Client request long running operation to begin 
Server sends multiple updates to the clients WCF host as work progresses.
Server sends work complete to client.

This leaves your client free to do other things, consuming the messages from the server as you see fit. Maybe updating a status area as messages come in.

You could even get the server to maintain a list of clients and send updates to them all.

--------EDIT--------- 
When I say WCF host I mean a [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553788%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
It can be created automatically from your XML in App.config or though code directly.

```
var myUri = new Uri[0];
myUri[0] = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:4000");
var someService = new SomeService(); //implements ISomeService interface
var host = new ServiceHost(someService, myUri);
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(); // need to configure this
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISomeService), binding, "");
host.Open();
```

Proxy is a term I use for what a client uses to connect to the server, it was in an early example I came across and its stuck with me since. Again can be created both ways.

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(); // need to configure this
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:4000");
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ISomeService>(binding, endpointAddress);
var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
proxy.DoSomeWork();
```

So in a typical client/server app you have

```
CLIENT APP 1       SERVER APP         CLIENT APP 2
proxy------------->ServiceHost<-------proxy
```

What I am suggesting is that you can make the client be a "server" too

```
CLIENT APP 1       SERVER APP         CLIENT APP 2
proxy------------->ServiceHostA<------proxy
ServiceHostB<------proxy1
                   proxy2------------>ServiceHostB
```

If you do that, you can still split your large task into smaller ones if needed (you mentioned memory issues), but from the sounds of things they still might take some time and this way progress updates can still be sent back to the client or even all clients if you want everyone to be aware of whats happening. No callbacks needed, though you can still use them if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your input. When you say "WCF host", do you mean "service proxy" ? Do you mean that I can instanciate two different service proxy, each one listening to a different service method ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoiding EF update concurrency problems.

   See this question/answer [Long running Entity Framework transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180466/long-running-entity-framework-transaction)
2. Improving speed.

   Some suggestions:

   - Try using SQL Profiler to see what SQL query is being executed, and optimize the linq query
   - Or try improving the query itself or calling a stored procedure.
   - Can the updates be done in parallel? different threads? different processors?
3. Informing the user of the progress.

   I would suggest changing the client to call an async method, or a method which then starts the long running operation asynchronously.  This would return control back to the client immediately. Then it would be up to the long running operation to provide feed back as to its progress.

   See this article for [updating progress from a background thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

   *Update*
   the "architecture" I would suggest would be as follows:

```
              . Service . . .
    ________  .    _________    _______    ____
   |        | .   |   WCF   |  |  EF   |  |    |
   | Client |---->| Service |->| Class |->| DB |
   |________| .   |_________|  |_______|  |____|
              .
              . .
```

The WCF service is only responsible for accepting client requests, and starting off the long running operation in the EF Class.  The client should send an async request to the WCF service so it retains control and responsiveness.  The EF class is responsible for updating the database, and you may choose to update **all** or a **subset** or records at a time.  The EF class can then notify the client via the WCF service of any progress it has made - as required.

Comment: About point number 3 : I would like to know if it's better to call a WCF method that will do all the updates, or call a WCF method multiple times for each entity I have to update ?

Comment: I would recommend a single wcf method and let a separate class deal with the specifics.  i.e. the wcf service method is only responsible for communication.  see updated answer